# Export Spatial Lines Data Frame with writeOGR in R

Tags: r, rgdal

I can use writeOGR to write a shape file in R, but it's only working for spatial points data frames, and not spatial lines data frame.

This is the code I'm using. The dataframe is called `HDOT2015_Bridge`.

```
writeOGR(HDOT2015_Bridge,dsn="~/Desktop/HDOT2015/Bridges",
         layer="HDOT2015_Bridge",driver="ESRI Shapefile",morphToESRI = T)
```

The error says

```
Error in writeOGR(HDOT2015_Bridge, dsn = "~/Desktop/HDOT2015/Bridges",  : 
  Creation of output file failed
```

Comment: please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Wild guess: does the ouput folder exist?

Comment: The output folder exists. I can use pretty much the same code for a "SpatialPointsDataFrame" but when I try to export it with writeOGR and it's a "SpatialLinesDataFrame" I can't get it to work.  Do I need to use a different driver than "ESRI Shapefile"?

Comment: What kind of example can I provide? I'm not sure how to show the problem more than what I shared above.

Comment: Ok.  Sorry for the stupid question,  but it happened to me lots of times.... Id say that you could share the file,  if. Possible.  Also,  i never used morphtoesri.  What it is supposed to do? Did you try removing it?

Comment: I meant,  the data frame.